# Can you link Access 2010 front end to Access 2003 back end?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, linked-tables

Maybe I haven't had enough cawphee but teh googles are failing me at the moment.  Before I undertake this huge job within my company, does anyone know if a 2010 front end can link to a 2003 back end?

Comment: You should be able to use linked tables.  The transport should just be a jet odbc connection.  Alternatively, to go all out, you can connect it to a linked server (MSACCESS Linked server), then you also have an upgrade path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can link from a 2010 front end to a 2003 back end. Is the 2003 back end already created? If so, is there a compelling reason not to upgrade the 2003 back end to a 2010 back end? If not, is there a compelling reason not to create the back end as a 2010 file?